# Pattern to allow letters, numbers and spaces between 5 and 40 characters

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to use HTML5 patterns to validate an input, but I can't get to validate an input with only letters, numbers and spaces between 5 and 40 characters.

What I currently have is:

```
required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,40}"
```

Which allows letters and numbers between 5 and 40 chars, but I don't know how to also allow spaces in it.

Comment: Just add a space: `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` (see the space after the `9`).

Comment: @sp00m Very nice thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

Added a space after `0-9`.

Use  this  [website](http://html5pattern.com/Names) for future reference. URL : http://html5pattern.com/Names

Answer (score -1):

Try this
"[a-z|A-z|0-9|\s]{5,40}"

Or alternatively
"[a-z|A-z|0-9|\s]{5,40}"

Comment: The bar | acts as a OR gate on most regex engines, it would seem this is not the case for javascript. This answer would be useful for those who needed the same regex for say the .NET platform.

Comment: Not when nested between brackets, they are then matched literally (whatever the programming language). Brackets create a character class, more details at http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.